# libcurl how do I know a transfer is complete when using multi interface?

Tags: libcurl

I know it's not a problem when using the easy interface because after curl_easy_perform returns the transfer is complete. But how do I know that when using the multi interface?
After going through the document. This is the only way I came up with so far:

```
class CompleteListener {
public:
  virtual void onComplete(CURLcode) = 0;
};

CURLMsg* msg = curl_multi_info_read(...);
void* ptr;
if(msg && msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE)
{
    curl_easy_getinfo(msg->easy_handle, CURLINFO_PRIVATE, &ptr);
    static_cast<CompleteListener*>(ptr)->onComplete(msg->data.result);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that now all private pointer must point to an instance of derived class of CompleteListener. If there is a way to get the pointer stored in CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, I can also just store a callback inside CURLOPT_PRIVATE.

Answer (score 1):

When you call [curl_multi_perform()](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html) (or [curl_multi_socket_action()](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_socket_action.html)) you include a pointer to a counter that returns the number of currently "active" transfers. When that counter gets decreased, or even reaches zero, you know that one or more transfers were completed.

When you call [curl_multi_info_read()](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_info_read.html) (perhaps after you called `curl_multi_perform()`), it can return a pointer to a message from libcurl that can tell you the easy handle of a completed transfer (and its return code). If there are more than one transfer completed, repeated calls to the function will return more information until you get NULL back when there's no more info to get.

You can find this used in numerous of [the examples](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html) hosted on the curl web site, for example the [multi-app](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-app.html) one.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't make myself clear. My real question is how do I let the user of `easy_handle` know when the transfer is complete. In the context of  `curl_multi_socket_action` I don't know the user. In the context of `curl_multi_info_read`, I  can get the user through `CURLINFO_PRIVATE`. But I can't find  a way to store a callback so that I can notify it. `CURLOPT_PRIVATE` and all the other data opts, `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` and the likes, are the same object  for me. If I can get access to any of it. I can store the callback inside `CURLINFO_PRIVATE`.

Comment: I don't see how that's even a question of how you use libcurl. You know when the transfer associated with a specific easy handle is done, then how you "tell the user" that is not really libcurl's business. It performed the transfer to completion, the rest is up to your application.